# robots.txt with Disallow and meta tag that allows

Tags: meta-tags, robots.txt

I am responsible for a site with a base URL such as:
*https://hello.world.com/my-site/*

There is a robots.txt file in *https://hello.world.com/robots.txt* with the following content:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

There is no way for me to edit or delete or affect that file in any way.

I can, however, put <meta> tags in all the pages under *https://hello.world.com/my-site/* .
I know I can add, for example:

```
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
```

My question is: will Google and other search engines give more preference to my meta tag under *https://hello.world.com/my-site/* , or to *https://hello.world.com/robots.txt*?

Answer (score 1):

Robots.txt directives are **crawler directives**, while meta tags are **indexer directives**. All indexer directives require crawling. Therefore, nothing you do in your meta will make a difference if robots.txt is set to disallow.

From https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag

> Robots meta tags and X-Robots-Tag HTTP headers are discovered when a
>   URL is crawled. If a page is disallowed from crawling through the
>   robots.txt file, then any information about indexing or serving
>   directives will not be found and will therefore be ignored. If
>   indexing or serving directives must be followed, the URLs containing
>   those directives cannot be disallowed from crawling.

(See also: http://moz.com/blog/robots-exclusion-protocol-101)

Answer (score 0):

register for and login to your google webmaster console to see if you can over-ride robots.txt settings in there - there is a section for it but i don't know if it lets you override or just gives tips.

definitely keep trying to change the robots.txt file - meta tags can not override robots.txt files, because robots.txt files essentially equate to a message like "crawl" / "nocrawl" rather than "index" / "noindex" - so when google sees it can't crawl, it never checks to see if it can index but even if it could it still can't crawl.

Answer (score -1):

Google will use both, first the robots.txt to look with Path they can access.

And then Google looks for the Meta, with the Meta you can better control from a Script what pages they put in the Index and/or Follow.

I think you should use both. Put all Directories Google should not see like /js in the robots.txt und control the Meta Tag from the Controller Script, so you can set "noindex,follow" as an example. You can't do something like "noindex,follow" with the robots.txt.